# Flex child item disappear on very small widths

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm buiding a resize component using ReactJS. Code below:

```js
class Cell extends React.Component {
  handleMouseDown = event => {
    this.props.onMouseDown(this.props.index, event);
  };

  render() {
    let verticalGrip = ( <
      div onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      className = "cell-vertical-grip" / >
    );

    return ( <
      div className = "cell-container"
      style = {
        {
          width: this.props.widths[this.props.index]
        }
      } >
      <
      div className = "cell-content"
      style = {
        {
          border: "10px solid transparent"
        }
      } >
      {
        "WIDTH " + this.props.widths[this.props.index]
      } <
      /div> {
        verticalGrip
      } <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    widths: [100, 100, 100, 100],
    baseWidths: [100, 100, 100, 100],
    xBase: 0,
    resizeIndex: null
  };

  handleMouseDown = (index, event) => {
    console.log("MouseDown: index: " + index + ", pageX: " + event.pageX);

    this.setState({
      xBase: event.pageX,
      resizing: true,
      resizeIndex: index
    });
  };

  handleMouseMove = event => {
    if (this.state.resizing) {

      let delta = this.state.xBase - event.pageX;

      console.log("MouseMove " + delta);

      let widths = this.state.widths.slice();
      widths[this.state.resizeIndex] = this.state.baseWidths[this.state.resizeIndex] - delta;

      this.setState({
        widths: widths
      });
    }
  };

  handleMouseUp = event => {
    console.log("MouseUp");

    this.setState({
      resizing: false,
      resizeIndex: null
    });
  };

  render() {
    return ( <
      div className = "test-container"
      onMouseMove = {
        this.handleMouseMove
      }
      onMouseUp = {
        this.handleMouseUp
      } >
      <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        0
      }
      /> <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        1
      }
      /> <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        2
      }
      /> <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        3
      }
      /> <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render( <
  Test / > ,
  document.body
);
```

```css
.test-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.cell-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.cell-content {
  align-self: center;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.cell-vertical-grip {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 3px;
  min-width: 3px;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The `verticalGrip` is where you grab the column to resize.

All fine, but my problem appears when I resize any column to widths smaller than `20px`. In that situation, my blue grip (`verticalGrip` item) simply disappears. So, if I release the mouse on that position, I cannot expand the column again as there is no grip to grab (it has disappeared).

In other words, if he needs to shrink a column for some reason, he cannot grow it again as there is no grip to grab.

How can I keep my grip visible on every possible width, allowing the user to resize the column on any circumstance?

Comment: it's because of the 10px border you are adding to the element (2x10px = 20px)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to make your element to be sticky on the right and it will not disappear when there is an overflow due to the border you are applying to your element.

```js
class Cell extends React.Component {
  handleMouseDown = event => {
    this.props.onMouseDown(this.props.index, event);
  };

  render() {
    let verticalGrip = ( <
      div onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      className = "cell-vertical-grip" / >
    );

    return ( <
      div className = "cell-container"
      style = {
        {
          width: this.props.widths[this.props.index]
        }
      } >
      <
      div className = "cell-content"
      style = {
        {
          border: "10px solid transparent"
        }
      } >
      {
        "WIDTH " + this.props.widths[this.props.index]
      } <
      /div> {
        verticalGrip
      } <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    widths: [100, 100, 100, 100],
    baseWidths: [100, 100, 100, 100],
    xBase: 0,
    resizeIndex: null
  };

  handleMouseDown = (index, event) => {
    console.log("MouseDown: index: " + index + ", pageX: " + event.pageX);

    this.setState({
      xBase: event.pageX,
      resizing: true,
      resizeIndex: index
    });
  };

  handleMouseMove = event => {
    if (this.state.resizing) {

      let delta = this.state.xBase - event.pageX;

      console.log("MouseMove " + delta);

      let widths = this.state.widths.slice();
      widths[this.state.resizeIndex] = this.state.baseWidths[this.state.resizeIndex] - delta;

      this.setState({
        widths: widths
      });
    }
  };

  handleMouseUp = event => {
    console.log("MouseUp");

    this.setState({
      resizing: false,
      resizeIndex: null
    });
  };

  render() {
    return ( <
      div className = "test-container"
      onMouseMove = {
        this.handleMouseMove
      }
      onMouseUp = {
        this.handleMouseUp
      } >
      <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        0
      }
      /> <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        1
      }
      /> <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        2
      }
      /> <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        3
      }
      /> <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render( <
  Test / > ,
  document.body
);
```

```css
.test-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.cell-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.cell-content {
  align-self: center;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.cell-vertical-grip {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 3px;
  min-width: 3px;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  background-color: blue;
  
  position:sticky;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can consider another idea instead of border like outline or box-shadow that will not affect the width of the element and you will have the same visual output:

```js
class Cell extends React.Component {
  handleMouseDown = event => {
    this.props.onMouseDown(this.props.index, event);
  };

  render() {
    let verticalGrip = ( <
      div onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      className = "cell-vertical-grip" / >
    );

    return ( <
      div className = "cell-container"
      style = {
        {
          width: this.props.widths[this.props.index]
        }
      } >
      <
      div className = "cell-content"
      style = {
        {
          outline: "10px solid #fff"
        }
      } >
      {
        "WIDTH " + this.props.widths[this.props.index]
      } <
      /div> {
        verticalGrip
      } <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    widths: [100, 100, 100, 100],
    baseWidths: [100, 100, 100, 100],
    xBase: 0,
    resizeIndex: null
  };

  handleMouseDown = (index, event) => {
    console.log("MouseDown: index: " + index + ", pageX: " + event.pageX);

    this.setState({
      xBase: event.pageX,
      resizing: true,
      resizeIndex: index
    });
  };

  handleMouseMove = event => {
    if (this.state.resizing) {

      let delta = this.state.xBase - event.pageX;

      console.log("MouseMove " + delta);

      let widths = this.state.widths.slice();
      widths[this.state.resizeIndex] = this.state.baseWidths[this.state.resizeIndex] - delta;

      this.setState({
        widths: widths
      });
    }
  };

  handleMouseUp = event => {
    console.log("MouseUp");

    this.setState({
      resizing: false,
      resizeIndex: null
    });
  };

  render() {
    return ( <
      div className = "test-container"
      onMouseMove = {
        this.handleMouseMove
      }
      onMouseUp = {
        this.handleMouseUp
      } >
      <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        0
      }
      /> <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        1
      }
      /> <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        2
      }
      /> <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        3
      }
      /> <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render( <
  Test / > ,
  document.body
);
```

```css
.test-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.cell-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
/*to push the element so we can see the outline*/
.cell-container:before {
  content:"";
  width:10px;
}

.cell-content {
  align-self: center;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.cell-vertical-grip {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 3px;
  min-width: 3px;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. `position: sticky` saved my day.

Comment: @Mendes added another way ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be to revise your CSS a little so that your gripper elements are positioned with `absolute`, aligned and sized to the right edge and height of the parent `.cell-container`:

```
.cell-vertical-grip {
  /* Add this */
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  right:0;
}
```

You would also explicity set the `min-width` of `.cell-container` to match the gripper width, so that it is still visible when the container is fully collapsed:

```
.cell-container {
  /* Add this */
  min-width:3px;
  position:relative;
}
```

I've updated your code with these changes which are working in the snippet below:

```js
class Cell extends React.Component {
  handleMouseDown = event => {
    this.props.onMouseDown(this.props.index, event);
  };

  render() {
    let verticalGrip = ( <
      div onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      className = "cell-vertical-grip" / >
    );

    return ( <
      div className = "cell-container"
      style = {
        {
          width: this.props.widths[this.props.index]
        }
      } >
      <
      div className = "cell-content"
      style = {
        {
          border: "10px solid transparent"
        }
      } >
      {
        "WIDTH " + this.props.widths[this.props.index]
      } <
      /div> {
        verticalGrip
      } <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    widths: [100, 100, 100, 100],
    baseWidths: [100, 100, 100, 100],
    xBase: 0,
    resizeIndex: null
  };

  handleMouseDown = (index, event) => {
    console.log("MouseDown: index: " + index + ", pageX: " + event.pageX);

    this.setState({
      xBase: event.pageX,
      resizing: true,
      resizeIndex: index
    });
  };

  handleMouseMove = event => {
    if (this.state.resizing) {

      let delta = this.state.xBase - event.pageX;

      console.log("MouseMove " + delta);

      let widths = this.state.widths.slice();
      widths[this.state.resizeIndex] = this.state.baseWidths[this.state.resizeIndex] - delta;

      this.setState({
        widths: widths
      });
    }
  };

  handleMouseUp = event => {
    console.log("MouseUp");

    this.setState({
      resizing: false,
      resizeIndex: null
    });
  };

  render() {
    return ( <
      div className = "test-container"
      onMouseMove = {
        this.handleMouseMove
      }
      onMouseUp = {
        this.handleMouseUp
      } >
      <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        0
      }
      /> <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        1
      }
      /> <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        2
      }
      /> <
      Cell widths = {
        this.state.widths
      }
      onMouseDown = {
        this.handleMouseDown
      }
      index = {
        3
      }
      /> <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render( <
  Test / > ,
  document.body
);
```

```css
.test-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.cell-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;

  /* Add this */
  min-width:3px;
  position:relative;
}

.cell-content {
  align-self: center;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: white;
}

.cell-vertical-grip {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 3px;
  min-width: 3px;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  background-color: blue;

  /* Add this */
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```